# Using VBSCRIPT to pass calling URL to called page

Tags: vbscript

I guess I need vbscript to solve this task.

I have 5 `foster mother` pages that can call a `daughter` page.

`Daughter` page can call 3 different `Friend` pages and be returned to `daughter` page.

I want the `daughter` page to be able to go back to it's called foster parent

for example:

> > "myurl = homepage 1.htm"
> >
> > "myurl = homepage 2.htm
> >
> > "myurl = homepage 3.htm" etc

So `daughter` will have "myurl" as either homepage 1 or 2 or 3 etc.

window-history-back doesn't work in this case as `daughter` would end up returning to the previous called `friend` page.

This is on client side PC's so cannot use server side methods.

Comment: silly question- does 'call' mean it forwards to other "Cat In St. Ives" page or gets content from it? Kind of confusing...